# Почему не видит функцию из прототипа?

Tags: javascript

Решил написать свой полифил для bind, функцию, которую оборачивать, планирую брать из this. Но получаю ошибку, что не видит мою функцию, что я записал в прототип.

```
function func1() {
    console.log(func1.prototype);
}
func1.prototype.bind2 = function (){
    var func = this;
    console.log(func);
};
var obj = {
    a: "a"
};
func1();
func1.bind2();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А так: `func1().bind2()`. ?

Comment: Prototype имеет смысл только у конструктора `new func1()`, разве нет?

Comment: а почему он должен видеть?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы добавляете функцию через `prototype`, то эта функция будет доступна после создания объекта. Если вам нужно вызывать функцию без использования оператора `new`, то добавьте ее к функции также, как к объекту.

```js
function func1() {
  console.log('func1');
}

func1.bind = function() {
  console.log('bind');
};

func1.prototype.bind2 = function() {
  console.log('bind2');
};

func1();
func1.bind();

var f = new func1();
f.bind2();
```